# Are the familiars you summon the same everytime?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, summoning

If I summon a familiar and it dies, when I resummon it, is it another spirit taking the same form?

If I just recast the *find familiar* spell, and get it to assume a new form I assume It's the same spirit.

> Your familiar transforms into the chosen creature.

But is the same the case for when the familiar dies?

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form you choose

> When the familiar drops to 0 Hit Points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. **It** reappears after you cast this spell again.

> As an action while it is temporarily dismissed, you can cause **it** to reappear in any unoccupied space within 30 feet of you.

> If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause **it** to adopt a new form.

**It** is always the same spirit. Oh, and familiars don’t “die” - they “disappear” because while the “animal form” is a creature, the “spirit” isn’t.