# What happens to a petrified familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, conditions

A wizard's familiar was recently petrified by a magical item (similar effect to a medusa). The item's description states that only spells such as *greater restoration* or *wish* can reverse the effect.

Right now, the wizard is carrying around a stone owl, so RAW, what are his options?
If he dismisses it to a pocket dimension, would it come back still in stone?
If he destroys it then summons it back, would it be stone (on the grounds that it doesn't die, just disappears and returns in a different form)?

Comment: Related: "[Are the familiars you summon the same everytime?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174865)" and "[What happens when a familiar from the Find Familiar spell “dies”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49716)" and "[Will my familiar remember me when I re-summon it, or is it a new entity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157689)" and "[Can you change a recently deceased familiar’s form when recasting the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177642)"

Comment: Is this a familiar summoned using the *find familiar* spell?

Comment: @BaconyRevanant: There are indeed other ways to get a familiar - i.e. by making a contract with an actual creature in the world (e.g. a real imp or pseudodragon or gazer). Most questions around familiars do relate to the *find familiar* spell (especially given the references in this question to "dismissing it to a pocket dimension" or "destroying it then summoning it back"), but it's good to make sure. :)

Comment: @V2Blast What book is that from that says you can gain a familiar without the use of the *Find Familiar* spell?

Comment: @BaconyRevanant: It's referenced in the "Variant: Familiar" sidebars for a few creatures in the *Monster Manual* and *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (the [imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp-familiar-variant), [pseudodragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pseudodragon-familiar-variant), [quasit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit-familiar-variant), and [gazer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gazer-familiar)). Such a familiar is a real creature that chooses to form a contract with a spellcaster, rather than a spirit that merely takes an animal's form.

Comment: You can see such variant familiars referenced in these Q&As: [Is it possible to have two familiars?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87211/33569), [Can wizards have familiars without the use of the find familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51263/33569)

Comment: @BaconyRevanant Note that the variant familiar rules are intended for use by the DM for NPC spellcasters, and not for player characters (unless the DM specifically allows it). Also, keep in mind that how the *find familiar* spell works has no bearing on variant familiars, or vice versa; they're totally different game mechanics, not intended to be used together.

Comment: @V2Blast OK, so I have a physical copy of Volo's, and that's not how I remember reading the "this can be a familiar" sidebar on Gazers, I read it as more of a "this creature is an additional option for when you cast *Find Familiar*." I haven't read that in a while, so I'll have to look back over it when I get home.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Sending the familiar to its pocket dimension doesn't help.

Making the familiar go to its pocket is merely movement and has nothing to do with the familiar's physical condition. It doesn't regain HP or shed any conditions when this happens.  It might be more convenient to carry around a petrified animal by tossing it into an extradimensional space, but it won't solve the root problem.

### Casting *find familiar* should fix the issue.

The [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell says:

> When the familiar drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. It reappears after you cast this spell again.

So if it's killed, the familiar leaves behind no physical form when it vanishes, and when it reappears, the clear intent is that it comes back with a brand new body at full HP, bearing none of the injuries that killed it.

If it "reappears" without any injuries, I think it's logical to assume that any *other* effects attached to its old body are similarly left behind, whether that's poison, a curse, or petrification. (Or, for that matter, blessings and other beneficial effects.)

Comment: As a note to technicality, Petrification does not inflict damage or otherwise reduce Hit Points, nor does it directly cause death, it is merely a condition. Similarly, casting *Find Familiar* again doesn't *say* that it clears a familiars status conditions like being blinded or petrified. That being said, I agree with your answer, if you're making it a new body when you cast the spell, there's no reason that the new body would be subject to any adverse conditions affecting the old body.

Comment: @BaconyRevanant I didn't intend to imply that petrification deals damage. I was referring to the OP's question about what would happen if he destroyed the familiar and resummoned it.  I've edited to make that more clear.

Comment: I wasn't saying that you did imply that. But since you left it out of your answer, I was just pointing out that by strict RAW reading, the familiar being petrified doesn't automatically kill it, and turning it into a new creature doesn't RAW clear any conditions it's suffering from. You would have to remove the condition with an effect that would specifically do so, such as *Greater Restoration*.

Comment: Right, and I agreed with you on that point. All I've been trying to say is the actual RAW should be in the answer as well, it shouldn't just be "this is how I would do it"

Comment: Worth noting that if he doesn't actually care about his familiar, he can dismiss it and summon a new one.  Nothign abotu being stone prevents that.  Other than that... the resummoning is described as "transformed".  The medusa's gaze causes the Petrified condition, which is also described as transformed.  It also mentions "The petrification lasts until the creature is freed by the Greater Restoration spell or other magic."  Seems like transforming again via find familiar would count as "other magic".

Comment: "If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form. Choose one of the forms from the above list. Your familiar transforms into the chosen creature." - the "transform" bit seems pretty unambiguous to *me*.

Comment: Yeah, okay, I'll update my answer.